# 80's/90's anime, robot car fight, including a silver Beetle-like car with yellow wheels and a spinning device to destroy other cars

Tags: story-identification, anime

One anime stuck in my mind that I was watching everyday, I got some memory about that anime is, they were creating robot/cars and fight with each other.

Good side had a Beetle kind of car (silver color) with yellow color wheels and they had something spinning on the front to destroy the opponent's robot/car.

Opponent side had one girl and two men(robot/car builder and to drive).And one guy had to change his side. On the other side there were one girl and boy, I think.

Comment: Hi there! That's some info already, but could you please take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?  Anything that the guide would remind you of, even if seems minor - everything may help in getting you an answer. Cheers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your description sounds a lot like [Time Bokan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bokan) ([this](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/time-bokan) is the link to its page in anime planet).

It is the first of a series of different comic animes (Time Bokan, Yatterman, Yattodetaman...), usually revolving about a boy and a girl as the heroes and a trio (a girl and two men, one being a genious, with thin corporature and a long nose, while the other one being a super-strong man) as the villains.

They travel in the different epoch of time, usually searching for a person or a treasure (in the case of Time Bokan, they look for a lost scientist).

So, for this series:

> Good side had a Beetle kind of car (silver color) with yellow color wheels and they had something spinning on the front

[image]

> Opponent side had one girl and two men(robot/car builder and to drive).And one guy had to change his side. On the other side there were one girl and boy, I think.

[image]

Comment: Oh so it was a _bug_ beetle! I was trying to spot Volkswagen Beetles! :D